# Canonical equivalence in Pattern

Tags: java, regex

I am referring to the test harness listed here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/test_harness.html

The only change I made to the class is that the pattern is created as below:

```
Pattern pattern = 
        Pattern.compile(console.readLine("%nEnter your regex(Pattern.CANON_EQ set): "),Pattern.CANON_EQ);
```

As the tutorial at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pattern.html suggests I put in the pattern or regex as `a\u030A` and string to match as `\u00E5` but it ends on a No Match Found. I saw both the strings are a small case 'a' with a ring on top.

Have I not understood the use case correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing has nothing to do with the `Pattern.CANON_EQ` flag.

Input read from the console is not the same as a Java string literal. When the user (presumably you, testing out this flag) types `\u00E5` into the console, the resultant string read by `console.readLine` is equivalent to `"\\u00E5"`, not "å". See for yourself: http://ideone.com/lF7D1

As for `Pattern.CANON_EQ`, it behaves exactly as described:

```
Pattern withCE = Pattern.compile("^a\u030A$",Pattern.CANON_EQ);
Pattern withoutCE = Pattern.compile("^a\u030A$");
String input = "\u00E5";

System.out.println("Matches with canon eq: "
    + withCE.matcher(input).matches()); // true
System.out.println("Matches without canon eq: "
    + withoutCE.matcher(input).matches()); // false
```

http://ideone.com/nEV1V

Comment: Yes and no.  A string is a string is a string, but you are correct in the sense that a string read from the console needs no further escaping, while a string literal does need escaping.

Comment: @AdamMihalcin good correction. I've fleshed out my answer a bit more, with a demo to hopefully illustrate the difference in escaping.